# Blurry vertical sections using fglrx with Radeon hd 6970

Tags: drivers, screen, fglrx

So I managed to get fglrx working by downloading the drivers from ATI because the ones from additional drivers boot to a black screen and the open source dont let me change resolution. My one issue is that half of my monitor is fine and the other half is blurry almost as if there's a blurry vertical stripe on the right side. I tried disabling Compiz and have the same issue in both gnome and kde, I was wondering if theres an xorg.conf change that could be made to fix this as I have already set the resolution and refresh rates to the correct values.

Comment: I am having the same problem. My screen has like 200px blurred vertical line, then 200px good quality lines (not blurred) and then again line with blurred colors, etc. This pissed me off really hard. I am using Ubuntu 11.04. My laptop is Sony Vaio VPCEB1S1E (ATI 5650 video card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem went away with the latest version of Ubuntu.
The version that was used previously was 10.10 and I can probably safely say the problem occurs in older versions as the version of ATI's driver that supports the HD 69xx series were incompatible with 10.10 and below although installing the driver from the ATI website works (albeit with the vertical lines) because the driver from Additional Drivers causes you to drop to a shell or panic because fglrx crashes upon startup.

Comment: Could you tag your question with the version of Ubuntu you had the problem with and edit your answer to clarify which version you upgraded to/installed to fix the problem? This will make the question and answer clearer in the future. Also, you may accept your own answer by clicking on the tick.